# Bug in my mail sending program in Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am trying to create a mail sending script using smtp server and Python.
I am using csv to store the addresses, and then the script use them to create sending request using email lib.

```
for f, t in zip(FROM,TO):
    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    msg['From']= f
    msg['To'] = t  
    s.sendmail(f, t, msg.as_string())
    sleep(5)
    print('from: '+str(msg['From']))  #for debuging
    print('[+] emali send from {} to {}'.format(f,t)) 
    s.quit()
```

here is the problematic part. It seems that all the emails are sent only from the first `msg[from]` that I define.

output:

```
from: asv@acdc.co.il
[+] emali send from asv@acdc.co.il to orhalimi@mailinator.com
from: asv@acdc.co.il
[+] emali send from sss@Nisha.com to  or@mailinator.com
```

`msg[from]` doesn't get change in the next round of the loop even if `f` changed. but `msg['To']` work without problem.

Really weird,
Thanks for any help.

**Edit: Show how msg is defined**

I make a multipart message that attach html with option to attach file.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
if not opts.subject: msg['Subject'] = ' '
else: msg['Subject'] = opts.subject
try:
    with open(opts.html,'r') as f:
        html = f.read()
    part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
except Exception as e:
    print('html: '+ str(e))

if(opts.file):
    try:
        with open(opts.file, 'rb') as f:
            maintype, subtype = 'application', 'octet-stream'
            part2 = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
            part2.set_payload(f.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part2)
        part2.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=opts.file)
        msg.attach(part2)

    except Exception as e:
        print('file: '+ str(e))
```

**Edit2: After trying the suggesting stuff**

You are right about the same behavior. when I added `print('To: '+str(msg['From']))` The output got stuck on the first value.
output:

```
from: asv@acdc.co.il
To: asv@acdc.co.il
[+] emali send from asv@acdc.co.il to orhalimi@mailinator.com
from: asv@acdc.co.il
To: asv@acdc.co.il
[+] emali send from sss@Nisha.com to  or@mailinator.com
```

but when I change it to replace and set them before its work.
output:

```
from: asv@acdc.co.il
To: orhalimi@mailinator.com
[+] emali send from asv@acdc.co.il to orhalimi@mailinator.com
from: sss@Nisha.com
To:  or@mailinator.com
[+] emali send from sss@Nisha.com to  or@mailinator.com
```

Anyone know why? I remember list can redefine easy in python.

Comment: Show us how `msg` is defined and initialized.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal runnable example?

Comment: I added my message code. the rest is getting the parser and split the csv.

Comment: Can you try del msg["From"] and set again or msg.replace_header('From', f)?

Comment: Also try to print msg['To'], even though you says its working, I think behavior should be same. like msg['From'], msg['To'] will also print the first record value.

Comment: Confirm if it works, I'll move it to answer.

Comment: Its work, strange. I though dictionary can be redefine easily .

Comment: Most likely its MIMEMultipart implementation, I am not aware of much in detail. But the reason why its happening is because its appending and not replacing. you can debug and check the length of msg['From'] and msg['To'] after each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because its appending and not replacing your msg attribute value.

You can use [replace_header](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.replace_header) or `del` .

If you use replace make sure the check of attribute exists or not.

```
if msg.has_key('From'):
    msg.replace_header('From', f)
else:
    msg['From'] = f
```

Other way is clearing the attribute, and assign value -

```
del msg['From']
msg['From'] = f
```

Comment: `>>> msg ={}
>>> msg['from']=1
>>> msg['from']=2
>>> msg['from']
2`

in interactive its replacing. strange but thanks anyway.

Comment: @OrHalimi : this behavior is for dict, you are using a MIMEMultipart

Comment: `MIMEMultipart` is subclass of `Message` (via `MIMEBase`). [Documentation for `Message.__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.__setitem__)